# Prolog If Then rules

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

Consider the decision-making situation defined by the following rules:

•   If it is a nice day and it is summer, then I go to the beach
•   If it is a nice day and it is winter, then I go to the canal boating resort
•   If it is not a nice day and it is summer, then I go to work
•   If it is not a nice day and it is winter, then I go to class
•   If I go to the beach, then I swim.
•   If I go to the canal boating resort , then I go boat riding
•   If I go boat riding or I swim, then I have fun.
•   If I go to work, then I make money.
•   If I go to class, then I learn something.

Follow the rules for the following situations (what do you conclude for each one?):

•   It is a nice day and it is summer.
•   It is not a nice day and it is winter.
•   It is a nice day and it is winter.
•   It is not a nice day and it is summer.

I am not able to form rules for the above problem. Please someone help me out.

Comment: 1. Create facts you defined. 2. Create function, based on that facts 3. Implemented those functions and you'll be done.

Comment: @gauravdave *predicates* would be written, not *functions*.

Answer (score 1):

you have a CNL (Controlled Natural Language) specification: rules and situations are expressed in a (very) restricted subset of English. So the focus of the assignment will be on handling the 'truth value' of the statements... In SWI-Prolog, we can write:

```
kb :- rules(Rs), maplist(writeln,Rs), situations(Ls), maplist(writeln,Ls).

rules(Rs) :- tokenize_atom('
    If it is a nice day and it is summer, then I go to the beach.
    If it is a nice day and it is winter, then I go to the canal boating resort.
    If it is not a nice day and it is summer, then I go to work.
    If it is not a nice day and it is winter, then I go to class.
    If I go to the beach, then I swim.
    If I go to the canal boating resort , then I go boat riding.
    If I go boat riding or I swim, then I have fun.
    If I go to work, then I make money.
    If I go to class, then I learn something. 
', L), maplist(downcase_atom,L,D), phrase(rule(Rs), D).

rule([r(C -> A)|Rs]) --> [if], condition(C), [,], [then], consequence(A), [.], rule(Rs).
rule([]) --> [].

situations(S) :- tokenize_atom('
    It is a nice day and it is summer.
    It is not a nice day and it is winter.
    It is a nice day and it is winter.
    It is not a nice day and it is summer.
',L), maplist(downcase_atom,L,D), phrase(situations(S), D).

situations([s(S)|Rs]) --> condition(S), [.], situations(Rs).
situations([]) --> [].

condition(and(A,B)) --> fact(A), [and], condition(B).
condition(or(A,B)) --> fact(A), [or], condition(B).
condition(C) --> fact(C).
consequence(C) --> fact(C).

fact(fact(true, What)) --> [it,is], what(What).
fact(fact(false, What)) --> [it,is,not], what(What).
fact(fact(true, Action)) --> [i], action(Action).

what([A,B,C]) --> [A,B,C].
what([A]) --> [A].

action(L) --> {between(1,6,N),length(L,N)},L.
```

and we get

```
?- kb.
r((and(fact(true,[a,nice,day]),fact(true,[summer]))->fact(true,[go,to,the,beach])))
r((and(fact(true,[a,nice,day]),fact(true,[winter]))->fact(true,[go,to,the,canal,boating,resort])))
r((and(fact(false,[a,nice,day]),fact(true,[summer]))->fact(true,[go,to,work])))
r((and(fact(false,[a,nice,day]),fact(true,[winter]))->fact(true,[go,to,class])))
r((fact(true,[go,to,the,beach])->fact(true,[swim])))
r((fact(true,[go,to,the,canal,boating,resort])->fact(true,[go,boat,riding])))
r((or(fact(true,[go,boat,riding]),fact(true,[swim]))->fact(true,[have,fun])))
r((fact(true,[go,to,work])->fact(true,[make,money])))
r((fact(true,[go,to,class])->fact(true,[learn,something])))
s(and(fact(true,[a,nice,day]),fact(true,[summer])))
s(and(fact(false,[a,nice,day]),fact(true,[winter])))
s(and(fact(true,[a,nice,day]),fact(true,[winter])))
s(and(fact(false,[a,nice,day]),fact(true,[summer])))
true 
.
```

now should be simpler to process the situations, inferring the actions...